# How to backup and restore full encrypted system partitions?

Tags: partition, lvm, backup, luks

I want to be able to do the following:

1. Install an arbitrary Linux distribution to one or more fully LUKS encrypted partitions (preferably one encrypted LVM group)
2. Backup those encrypted partitions onto an external drive
3. Delete/overwrite/destroy those partitions
4. At a later time boot off another system on the same machine, or an usb drive
5. Restore the removed partitions off my backup
6. Keep using my restored system like nothing happened

I want my backup to be easily replicable, and transferable over the internet if needed - ideally just a file.

What tools can I use for this? Are there any important caveats?

Comment: Look into the ```tar``` command.

Comment: @mkurz you can use `dd` to [clone a partition to a file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dd#Create_disk_image). So you can clone the LUKS encrypted partition with dd and restore it. But [it should be unmounted](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/240265/cloning-external-harddrive-encrypted-by-bitlocker-using-dd). You can read https://arstechnica.com/civis/threads/how-to-clone-encrypted-boot-disk-to-a-new-hard-drive.1478313/ too.

Comment: Does the backup also need to be encrypted? As long as stored safely, I would just backup data. If going over Internet encrypt as you send it. I believe in Pareto, better know as 80/20 rule. Or in my case only 20% of my data really is important and needs to be encrypted. But I do not put data on Internet and have multiple backups.